# SMB file transfer speeds too low over local LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, file-transfer, samba

I have built a file server for my home network. It has a 3TB Sata 3Gb/s HDD on a Dual Celeron Mini ITX mobo with 2GB DDR3 RAM. I have installed Ubuntu minimal runing off a flashdrive. I installed samba and configured it with webmin.

I bought a D-Link DSL-2730R router, [the specs](http://suporte.dlink.com.br/suporte/arquivos/DSL-2730R/MANUAIS/DSL-2730R_A1_Datasheet_20120514.pdf) says it is 10/100 and b/g. I connected the router to the server via ethernet, and configured samba via webmin.

My laptop is in a room next to my router. When transfering files from/to my Ubuntu laptop, I get about 1,5MB/s on Nautilus. If I place my laptop in the same room, 30cm of the router, I get about 2,5MB/s.

I used an android app to check for the wifi channel with less interference and set it to a channel with no other SSIDs on it, and I disabled WPA2PSK and left the wifi open (for a few minutes, just for testing). The speed increased to a peak of 2,8MB/s.

If I disable wifi and connect via ethernet I get speeds aroun 6,6~7,9 MB/s. (All the teste were performed with the same file, a 300MB file).

Then I tried [an android app to test local wifi LAN transfer speed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pzolee.android.localwifispeedtester&hl=en) and it says my link speed is 54Mbps, signal is -59 dBm, download is 6967Kbit/s and upload is 3545Kbit/s.

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/80378/file-transfer-speed-over-wifi-54g?rq=1) the top theoretical speed on 802.11g is 6.7MB/s, but I'm getting less than 25% of it.

Comment: Yes, theoretically. In the same answer it says practical 4MB/s (so now it's at 65%). A bit more down you'll see an answer stating a source which says maximum of 3,1MB/s. (so now it's 80%). And if you count that the SMB-protocol is **very** chatty you'll loose a lot there too because your client also has to upload chatter for the protocol, easily loosing the remaining 20%. You can see this too with cable. Its 6,6MB/s (100Mbps connection). 54Mbps, which is in practice e.g. 40Mbps , so 40% of the cable is 6,6 * 0.4 = 2,64MB/s which is what you are getting in good circumstances. So it all fits ;)

Comment: @Rik Great comment, could you please copy it and paste as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, theoretically the speed of 802.11g is 6.75MB/s. (54Mbps / 8 = 6.75MB/s)

In the [same answer](https://superuser.com/questions/80378/file-transfer-speed-over-wifi-54g#answer-80404) it says the practical speed is 4MB/s (so now the 2.5MB/s is at 63% instead of 37%) (counting 6.75MB/s and 4MB/s against 2.5MB/s).

A bit more down you'll see an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/80378/file-transfer-speed-over-wifi-54g#answer-82379) stating a [source](http://www.pixelbeat.org/speeds.html) which says maximum of 3,1MB/s. (so now your at 80%).

Now calculate that the SMB-protocol is know for being very "chatty"; you'll lose a lot there too because your client also has to upload/download chatter for the protocol, easily losing much of the remaining 20%.

---

But now look at it from another angle. Let's look at the cable speed. You said it was 6,6~7,9 MB/s on a cable (with 100Mbps). So you already loose almost half the speed using SMB via cable.

Now take the WiFi. Even if your "link"-speed is 54Mbps, your actual speed will be more like 40Mbps. (40Mbps / 8 = 5MB/s) 40Mbps is 40% of the 100Mbps of the cable. So when we take 40% of the speed of the cable we get 6,6MB/s * 0.40 = 2,64MB/s. And this is in optimum circumstances. (If you take 4MB/s from the quoted answer you'll get 2,11MB/s.

So it all fits ;)

---

Now **about the test** with the app you did. You're getting 6967Kbit/s. **This is Kbit/s**. It's a lot less than you actually think. It's 6,8Mbps (while you should be getting 30-40Mbps or at least 20Mbps like me). That's just 870KB/s = 0.85MB/s !!! So it's a wonder you're getting 2.0MB/s file-copies ;)
Did you do the client-test or the "SMB-test" ?? (I did the "client-test".)

(I only get 19520Kb/s download with the "client-test" to a pc 2 rooms over)

Comment: 6967Kbit/s in the SMB test, and yes, android is taking 10 seconds to download a 1MB file =/

Comment: Yep. finally got the smb-test here working too. 7290Kbit/s down 9248 Kbit/s up while the client-test (clean tcp) is between 16000-20000Kbit/s. I think with some tweaking you can get SMB transfers up to 3-4MB/s but that involves a lot of tweaking of the buffer size, MTU etc... and making sure there is no interference on the wifi-channels. Beyond that there is going to 802.11n but that's not always guarantee of higher speeds.

Comment: I asusme you are on 802.11g too?

Comment: Yes. I also tried 802.11n but i only get a 65Mbps link with my phone and tablet if i use that. (not much improvement but that's due to the limitations of my router and not being able to go to 5Ghz.) With the 65Mbps i did get a higher upload with the clean tcp (33000 up) but the download stayed at 18000. SMB-test was just as bad (7198 up/8134 down) But this is on a phone and tablet. The WiFi antennas are not as strong as that of a laptop i imagine.

Comment: BTW for the clean tcp transfers i mentioned i used the tcpserver on [this page](http://pzoleeblogen.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/wifi-speed-test-for-android-how-to/#ID-mobile-computer) from that app. You could also try other tcp speedtests between laptop and server like [this](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-basics/31220-how-fast-is-your-network-five-ways-to-measure-network-speed). (I tested the app on Galaxy S2 to my Windows 7 PC as server.)

Comment: this magic number 3 MB/s helped me to realize that my laptop was using Wifi instead of active cable connection to SMB